# Comparing unsigned integers with signed type

Tags: type-conversion, comparison, signed, unsigned-integer

Some languages do not have support for unsigned integers, like dart or Java.

I have two integer numbers `int a, b` that are really unsigned (basically hashes or bitfields), but have to be stored in the signed data types.

A comparison function is needed. The usual `a < b` will not work here, as it would wrongly interpret negative values to be smaller, while they are (in the desired unsigned interpretation) actually larger. Each of those two ranges are handled correctly if considered alone.

A working solution I came up with (in dart, but language shouldn't really matter) is

```
int compareAsUnsigned(int a, int b) {
  final signA = a.sign;
  final signB = b.sign;
  if (signA == signB) return a.compareTo(b);
  if (signA == -1 || signB == -1) return b.compareTo(a);
  return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Are there any efficent and / or elegant ways to get the **unsigned compare** for values stored in **signed** data types (a longer type is not available and all bits are used)?